# assigning colors to specific lines of geom_line

Tags: r, ggplot2

simply trying to create a way so that I can make 12 individual plots all with one different "player" being in color and the rest gray. I've done this before for geom_bar but for some reason geom_line I'm having issues as they all come out gray

```
mycolors <- c("commish" = "blue","kuney" = "gray78","heets" = 
"gray78","miller" = "gray78","adam" = "gray78","coleman" = 
"gray78","bhupen" = "gray78", "arvin" = "gray78","luke" = "gray78","dad" = 
"gray78","thomas" = "gray78","bery" = "gray78")

ggplot(df, aes(years, pts, fill = player))+
  geom_line(size = 1.2)+
  scale_fill_manual(
    values = mycolors,
    limits = names(mycolors)
  )+
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(2010:2019))+
  theme_classic()+
  geom_hline(yintercept = 900)
```

Comment: `geom_line` doesn't have a `fill`. Use `aes(......, color = player)` and `scale_color_manual` instead.

Comment: thank you so much axeman! that was the issue. it works now